# Method Delete Not Allowed - destroy() method Django

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, django-rest-framework

I have looked online for all possible solutions to this recurring question, but nothing I have tried works.

I have a view set that retrieves and creates certain information. For reference, retrieving and creating that information is specific to each user. If a user has already created an entry, they are not allowed to create another.

The two methods for retrieving and creating right now are as follows:

```
class MyViewSet(ModelViewSet):
  queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
  serializer_class = MySerializer

  def get_queryset(self):
    return self.queryset.filter(user=self.request.user.username)

  def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    result = MyModel.objects.filter(user=request.user.username)
    if (result):
      return Response(status=405)

    # Otherwise, create an entry for that user
```

The endpoint to both of these operations don't include any arguments in the URL. In other words, they are `GET /my-endpoint/` and `POST /my-endpoint/` (since each operation is specific to a user)

Right now, I am trying to add a DELETE operation using `destroy()`. I understand that a `destroy()` sometimes requires a pk, but from what I've seen online, you can bypass that by specifying `pk=None` as I've done below. As I mentioned before, `my-endpoint/` does not require any arguments or parameters in the URL so deleting an entry for a given user can be done by calling `DELETE my-endpoint/`.

As a result, I've got:

```
def destroy(self, request, pk=None):
  # This isn't being called when hitting DELETE my-endpoint/. Instead, I get an error as below
```

> [    "detail": "Method "DELETE" not allowed." ]

How can I resolve this knowing that I don't pass any arguments into `my-endpoint/` for DELETE?

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because omitting the arguments in the URL will cause the [router](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/3.12.4/rest_framework/routers.py#L89) to fetch either `create` or `list` (which is `POST` and `GET` respectively). But seeing that the request method is `DELETE`, it will complain because the only thing available for that endpoint is, as discussed, only `POST` and `GET`.

If you really want to support `DELETE` on the base url, you will have to override the mapping of routers that build the urls (from the link above). But probably the simplest way is to use [`actions`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing) to create a new endpoint that deletes without needing a pk:

```
class MyViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    ...
    @action(detail=False, methods=['DELETE'], url_path='delete')
    def my_custom_destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # will be called by DELETE my-endpoint/delete
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I’ve given that a go and that seems to work fine. However, I’m not super keen on redefining the endpoint to a different path. How would I override the mapping of routers to support a delete without a pk? I’ve taken a look at your link but I’m not really sure where to start to be completely honest.

Comment: I tried to override the mappings to support this, but I'm having some issues making it work with the other methods of `GenericViewSet` and `APIView`. I'll let you know once I manage to resolve it.